# How to use the content of a Context inside a reducer

Tags: react-redux, react-context

I load an essentially static configuration from the server using RTK Query which is parsed into a `Context` and used inside a `Provider`. I can happily use the configuration in elements with a `useConfiguration()` hook.

However, I want to use the configuration when processing actions.

Is it possible to get the content of the `Context` in a reducer?

Of course, I can pass the entire configuration as part of the action payload, but would like to avoid doing this. The reason is that the configuration is large (making the serialised actions large?), and it makes it more difficult to create actions in Storybook stories.

Here is the context:

```
export const ConfigurationProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const { data } = api.useGetConfigurationQuery()
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(configurationReducer, initialState)
  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({ configuration: state, dispatch }),
    [state, data]
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      dispatch({ type: 'parse', payload: data })
    }
  }, [data])

  return (
    <ConfigurationContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </ConfigurationContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Here is where I want to use the configuration:

```
const mySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'mySlice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(quoteAction.addItem, (state, action) => {
      // How can I get the configuration here.
    })
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the slice and the api are part of the same storage, like so:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { configurationReducer } from './reducers/config';
import { api } from './api';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    configuration: configurationReducer,
    [api.reducerPath]: api.reduer
  },
  middleware: [api.middleware],
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);

export default store;
```

Then, you can access the API through the state argument in your reducer, like so:

```js
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(quoteAction.addItem, (state, action) => {
      let config = state.api.queries.getConfiguration.data ?? {}
    })
  }
```

This is not a subscription in the sense of RTK Query, though. So, you need to catch the API being uninitialized or the data outdated, etc.